# IM integration into Office Online or Office 365

Tags: outlook, office365, lync

is it possible to develop and integrate 3rd party IM provider into Office Online/Office 365 in the similar fashion as it was into Office 2010/2013/2016:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/integrating-im-applications-with-office

I'm trying to find any information on this topic but my google kung-fu is failing me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You could use the WOPI protocol to integrate with Office Online. Please refer to the following links：

[Office 365 Features & Benefits](http://www.telexperts.net/office-365-integration-services/)

[Using the WOPI protocol to integrate with Office Online](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Integrate with Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/integration/integrate-with-office)

Comment: This doesn't really look like the integration I'm referring to. I'm not trying to create custom Office app, I rather want to completely replace Lync/Skype for Business inside Outlook.

Comment: Did you ever find anything regarding this? I'm looking for the same thing

Comment: @CJScholten unfortunately I didn't, the project ended after we were done with the 2010/2013/2016 integration